# Modal Window with background blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I've the following mockup

[image]

To the left is a list of names and an arrow (currently I've shown this on Todd and Patricia, but this will be available on each name). On clicking the arrow I'm supposed to open a Modal Window.

Currently I'm opening the [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) dialog on click of the arrow.

Is it possible to achieve the UI as shown in the image using the modal dialog?

Is it possible to click on Hasen, Todd's arrow and load the modal dialog with new data without closing the modal dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit:

To achieve the UI shown in the screenshot you have provided, where the selected `li` sits on top of the overlay (`modal`) and "connects" to the dialog, you have to do the following:

1. Position the dialog next to the clicked `li`, and disable dragging & resizing.
2. Style the selected `li` to extend further (`width`) and apply `position: relative` + a high `z-index` so it sits on top of the overlay.
3. Do some CSS magic, so it will look good! :-)

I've written an updated JSFiddle to perfectly demonstrate what I've described above. I'm confident that you can proceed on your own from here. Personally, I think it looks neat, and almost identical to your screenshot.

Result of JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/Dmp94/3/embedded/result/
[(see code)](http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/Dmp94/3/)

---

*(original answer:)*

Yes, this is possible. First, you create a `Dialog` object. Then bind a `.click` event handler on your list of names, with a callback that opens the dialog and set's the contents.

### Here is an exmaple:

**[JavaScript]**

---

```
var myDialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
})

$("ul#names > li").click(function() {
    var myName = $(this).data("name");

    /* Open Dialog */
    if(myDialog.dialog("isOpen") !== true)
        myDialog.dialog("open");

    /* Change dialog title */
    myDialog.dialog("option", "title", myName)

    /* Change dialog contents */
    myDialog.find("span.name").text(myName);
    myDialog.find("div.content").html("Set content here!");
})
```

**[HTML]**

---

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Hello, my name is: <span class="name"></span></p>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="names">
    <li data-name="Hasen"><a href="#">Hasen</a></li>
    <li data-name="Todd"><a href="#">Todd</a></li>
    <li data-name="Patricia"><a href="#">Patricia</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

You can set the contents using [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), or in any other way you want.

Here is a quick way to "customize" a jQuery UI theme: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
You can always use CSS to style the `.ui-` classes to your liking on your own.

Here is a JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/Dmp94/

Comment: I already have written the code, my question is to get the look and feel as in the UI. When I set modal:true its not possible http://jsfiddle.net/Dmp94/1/ I want to dither the backgound when the arrow is clicked (modal:true), the UI should dither everything except the name on which the click occured (Patricia in the mockup is not dithered out), even when things in the background are dithered allow the user to click on the arrow on any name to load that person's data.

Comment: I already have written the code, my question is to get the look and feel as in the UI. When I set modal:true its not possible jsfiddle.net/Dmp94/1 I want to dither the background when the arrow is clicked (modal:true), the UI should dither everything except the name on which the click occured (Patricia in the mockup is not dithered out), even when things in the background are dithered allow the user to click on the arrow on any other name (eg. Todd) to load the new person's data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - please see my updated answer, it has all you need to get this going.

Comment: this may be stupid, I'm not able to get the css and jquery toggle part right for the following structure. http://jsfiddle.net/XxAXw/

Comment: That does not help, please attach your relevant JavaScript and CSS to a revised JSFiddle. However, by a quick look - you're using a `table` inside your html, and that will not work with my code (which relies on `ul` + `li`'s) without some kind of modification.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35624/discussion-between-losnir-and-sds)

Comment: I was able to get everything but the arrow click on todd http://jsfiddle.net/XxAXw/16/

Comment: You have to use `position: relative` and a higher `z-index` than your modal overlay on the arrow's span.

Comment: That got it working. Thanks!!! Here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/XxAXw/18/

Comment: No problem. By the way, narrow down your `.click` selector to only the first `td`, right now it opens the dialog on the other columns too.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the pointer and your guidance!!! http://jsfiddle.net/XxAXw/20/